# Groups and Permission (Site Owners vs Custom group with full control)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions

I am having a sub-site to which there are 2 groups with full control, one is the default Owners group and another is custom group added by me, both groups have Full Control permission, but Why does this happen that only when user is in Site Owners group he can share the site with other users while the same user when in custom group with full control, cannot share the site with other users. I tried finding the reason but no luck can someone point out it to me

Answer (score 1):

If you go to site settings > site permissions in sharepoint 2013. You can change the default in Access Request settings in order to let members share this site. Refer the below image

[image]

It seems that only default group's members can share site with other users. An  [Article](http://www.techrevmarrell.com/change-the-default-groups-in-sharepoint-site/)  that I found claims that it may be because of some extra permissions granted behind the scenes to default groups.

You can make a group default by going to the group > setting > Set as Default Group. Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Please read the question again. @inferno wants to know the reason why only site owner group users has the ability to share the site and not the custom group users with full control.

Comment: @Swayam I know these steps but as Zakir mentioned i want to know reason or what are those extra permissions given to default groups whether it be Owners/Members/Visitors